# How can we print out only part of a string between two same symbols using pointer arithmetic in C

Tags: c

For example, if user enters "shsk*asdds*" and the desired output is "*asdds". Or if the user enters "ads@sdasd@", and the desired output is "sdasd". How should we code a function that can achieve this?

Comment: The second example doesn't seem to quite line up. Is it supposed to be `ads@sdasda` to `sdasda`?

Comment: Yes I made a typo

Comment: Could you edit your question to correct it, please?

Comment: You have two entirely different situations you are looking at in your question. The first can be addressed by `strstr()` and the second by a pair of pointers and two calls to `strchr()` a validation of both pointers and a subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

C finds the end of a string by looking for the null byte at the end. To get just the tail end of a string, you can make a pointer to your new start position.

```
const char str[] = "123456789"; // str points at '1'
const char *tail = str + 4;     // tail points at '5'
puts(tail); // starts at '1' and reads to the null byte: "56789"
```

This can potentially save a lot of memory and is how functions like [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) work.

The example above uses automatic memory, you don't have to worry about freeing it. But if `str` was allocated using `malloc` you have to be careful. The memory is "owned" by `str`, and `tail` is "borrowing" it. You only free `str`, not `tail`.

```
char *str = strdup("123456789"); // strdup allocates memory for you
char *tail = str + 4;
puts(tail);

free(str); // good
free(tail); // bad
```

Comment: how is this answer related to the question? how will it  print 456 from `123@456@789`?

Comment: @P__J__ They made a typo, and the examples remain unclear. So I did the best I could.

Comment: Yeah let's say if we want to print 456 from 123@456@789, how can we do that with the pointer arithmetic?

Comment: @dopez `printf("%.3s\n", "123@456@789"+4);`

Comment: @e2-e4 What about 12345@1@1. Will this printf work?

Answer (score 0):

```
void printbetween(const char *str, char delim)
{
    if(str)
    {
        while(*str && *str != delim) str++;
        if(*str) str++;
        while(*str && *str != delim) putc(*str++, stdout);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    printbetween("123@456@789", '@');
}
```